# How to protect a Google sheet: script that prevents adding rows

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet that is protected from ordinary users.

Elevated users can edit the sheet but I want to prevent the adding of rows or columns because the sheet size is predefined.

So protection of the sheet is not an option, I want to have a way where a user other than myself cannot click the add rows button or insert rows or columns. If it is not possible to avoid this, then they should be removed immediately and a warning message should pop up.

Thank you for looking at my request.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to protect an entire sheet to achieve your goal. You just need to protect *one full row* and *one full column*. For instance, it makes sense to choose the header row for protection. Then choose any full column that others will not ever need to modify (or add a column, protect that blank column, and then hide it). Grant editing permission only to yourself for that one row and one column.

This will allow others to edit any other editable portions of the sheet. But if they try to add or delete columns or rows, they won't be able to, because it would violate the protections set on your chosen single full-row or full-column above.

Comment: great idea, however I forgot to mention that I want to have the elevated users be able to hide and unhide rows

Answer (score 0):

**Follow these step to achieve the desired goal :**

1. Create an Installable Trigger that can catch the insertion of rows and columns. [On Change Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change)
2. Determine the user editing the sheet and apply the logic to all users besides the owner.
3. Get the starting point of the inserted rows/columns
4. Determine the number of rows/columns added
5. Delete the rows/columns using [Sheet.deleteColumns(columnPosition, howMany)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deletecolumnscolumnposition,-howmany)/[Sheet.deleteRows(rowPosition, howMany)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleterowsrowposition,-howmany) using the data collected above.
6. Show dialog box using [SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(prompt)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#alertprompt)

### Try this:

**Code:**

```
function onChange(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var fileID = ss.getId();
  var owner = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).getOwner().getEmail();
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  if(owner != user){
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
    if (e.changeType === 'INSERT_ROW'){
      var row = range.getRow();
      var lastRow = range.getLastRow();
      var numRows = 1+lastRow-row;
      sheet.deleteRows(row, numRows)
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Warning for Row");
    }else if (e.changeType === 'INSERT_COLUMN'){
      var col = range.getColumn();
      var lastCol = range.getLastColumn();
      var numCols = 1+lastCol-col;
      sheet.deleteColumns(col, numCols);
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Warning for Column");
    }
  }
}
```

**Installable Trigger Setup:**

[image]

**Demo:**

Column:

[image]

Row:

[image]

### References:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [Class SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
- [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)
- [Class Session](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session)
- [Class DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app)